# $X$ is $T_2$, $f$ is continuous. Is $f(X)$ $T_2$?

Tags: general-topology

Let, $f$ :$X$ $\rightarrow$ $Y$ be a nonconstant continuous map on topological spaces. Then , does it always imply that if $X$ is Hausdorff then $f(X)$ is Hausdorff? If not give me examples Please!

Comment: Trivial example: let $Y$ carry the indiscrete topology.

Comment: Take $X$ discrete and $Y$ indiscrete. Every $f$ is continuous, and $f(X)$ endowed with subtopology is also indiscrete. If it has  $2$ or more elementst then it is not Hausdorff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X = Y = \Bbb R$ (or any space with more than one point, really). Equip $X$ with the discrete topology. Equip $Y$ with the trivial topology. Consider the identity function $f : X \to Y$.